# Is it possible to access the front lcd screen for the vision pro?

Tags: visionos

Looking through the VisionOS SDK and I am wondering if we can access the front LCD of the VisionPro. Has anyone seen anything concerning this. I haven't discovered anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible at the moment.
Many features are missing from the Simulator at the moment which will probably get released in the future.

Comment: Even though the simulator doesn't show anything concerning the front screen. I was wondering if anyone has seen anything in VisionOS suggesting we will be able to gain access to the front LCD.

Comment: Pretty sure the Apple Docs would have mentioned this/have a category for this so I would assume no.